# MacBook's battery "Not Charging"?

Tags: battery, charging

My original battery died. I purchased a replacement battery. While this battery DOES hold charge, when it is on the charger, MacBook still states "Not Charging."

I've tried the SMC Reset, taking out the battery, even reinstalling OS! (I wanted to clean install Lion.)

The new battery is an Apple battery.

Why is it doing this?? Also, when I boot into Windows, there's no problem like that. (I need Windows for work. =( )

Here are the screenshots.

[image: Charging]

[image: Not charging]

Edit: Forgot to mention - there's no light when I put MacBook on charger. I've tried other chargers. I've tried charging other MacBook. It's not the adapter.

Comment: When this happens to my MacBook Pro I find disconnecting and reseating the magsafe charge connector in its port starts the charge cycle.

Comment: @IanC.: Same with me. Either that, or I wait for ten minutes, and it starts charging.

Comment: Does this happen all the time or is it only if you try to charge the laptop after it already has a certain amount of charge?

Answer (score 4):

Since you've already removed the battery and reset the SMC as mentioned in this [Apple Support KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964), your best bet is probably to bring in your MacBook to an Apple store to get checked out by one of the Genius techs. This is especially true since you've already replaced the battery with a new Apple battery.

Comment: Any geniuses out there? This is a late 2008 Unibody MacBook. Could the problem be with logic board?